# sed invalid reference on `s' command's RHS

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I keep getting the error:

```
sed 's/[a-z]* *[a-z]*/\2, \1/' teledir.txt | sort

sed: -e expression #1, char 24: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: You're using a back reference `\2` that you haven't defined. Please [edit] your question to explain what you want your `sed` substitution comnand to do

Comment: You need capture groups to use backreferences... try `sed 's/\([a-z]*\) *\([a-z]*\)/\2, \1/'`